# How to create a C++ library to sell it and Demo trial mode

Tags: class

I have created some C++ classes.
I want to sell them as a library.
What should I do so that no one can see how I implemented but he can use it.
Also I want to create a demo trial version of the library which expires after some time, how can I do this.

Thanks
Tarun

Answer (score 3):

If you distribute them compiled (`dll` or `so` extensions for example), then it won't be easy to see how you implemented them.

I gave an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192423/how-to-detect-a-system-date-roll-back) that might be helpful to create a trial version with time expiration.

If you're really paranoid, you can run your code through a C++ obfuscator.